# how can we fetch or integrate url in table row clickable in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i try to make in my below code using react when i click on table row one Assistance then fetch this URL
https://ibb.co/QFF4kCb  and show in web page and when i select the second Assistance row  then fetch this url https://ibb.co/526c7Pg  like that in all table row clickable and fetching the URL.

how can we do that  in react .

is there any help its very thankful.
i am pretty new in this table row clickable part.

anyone help me out this.

Comment: plz chck the code here https://codepen.io/sonynami/pen/PoWxNwX

Comment: anyone help me out this ??

Comment: Needs more details, where are these URLs stored? What does "fetch this URL" mean?

Comment: not url stored and all simply i want to make https://codepen.io/sonynami/pen/PoWxNwX in here

Comment: when i click on tble in  row then its clikable